# Replacing Webbrowser control with Listview - does Listview offer all features as Webbrowser?

Tags: vb.net, listview

I'm currently using Webrowser control on my form for navigating to paths on my PC. Everything is perfect - you can drag/drop files, cut/copy/paste them, navigate through folders, create new ones, files and icons are shown - as in Windows Explorer. Only problem I have is windows system security settings (PC at office). I keep getting Windows security alert "Do you want to allow files from this website to run on your computer?".

I wish to create Explorer on my own, so I started dealing with Listview. It's hard for my level of vb.net knowledge so before I proceed further I need to know this:

1. Can I show files + folders from desired path in Listview (like "C:\Myprograms\SomeFolder\") with all icons ?
2. Can I navigate in Listview - like when I have a folder in Listview and double click it to view It's contents
3. And can I drag/drop files in It and cut/copy/paste files, which will ultimately change my folders on PC ?

I'm asking this because I allready started and I've bumped into many problems - folder icons not showing (using different methods), folders and files not showing together in Listview, cut/copy/paste issues etc.

I just want to know If It's even possible. Thanks for response in advance.

Comment: `I just want to know If It's even possible`, short answer is **yes you can to all three questions**.

Comment: @Zaggler,thanks for that. Do you maybe have any link where I could see some coding where Listview enables all that ? I don't find nothing simmilar, only bits and pieces.

Comment: Welcome, you won't find much detail as to your request because usually a `ListView` is not used for this, but ***it can be done, but requires you to write custom code***.  `Do you maybe have any link where I could see some coding` also these questions are off topic here as we help with specific issues and or problems. Good Luck!

Comment: Ok, you allready answered me. Can be done, but not so easy :)

Comment: Correct, good luck!